# Invoke Pig Latin script from other Pig script

Tags: hadoop, user-defined-functions, apache-pig

I have a question about PIG Latin. Is there any way how to invoke some pig script from the other pig script?

I know it is possible to run user defined functions (UDFs) like:

```
REGISTER myudfs.jar;
A = LOAD 'student_data' AS (name: chararray, age: int, gpa: float);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE myudfs.UPPER(name);
DUMP B;
```

But it is not working for pig script. We are counting some different customer parameters and for readibility and reuse it would be great to load some pig snippets, something like:

```
REGISTER somepigscript.pig;
LOAD somepigscript.pig;
```

Do you know if there is any functionality like this? Or any UDF?

Thank you and have a good day...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pig has two commands, `RUN` and `EXEC`.  They differ in that `RUN` will execute the Pig script and leave its aliases and properties available for subsequent usage, while `EXEC` simply executes the script and returns with the calling environment unaltered (but with any new files created on HDFS available).

For example, I have a collection of macros, jars, and properties that I want to set at the beginning of every single script I write.  Rather than type them every time, I put that into a Pig script and call `RUN /my/script.pig` at the beginning of my scripts.

Comment: Thanks a lot Winnie. I think this is great practice how to operate with Pig scripts.

Comment: A few other notes: 1- shared startup commands in `/home/<username>/.pigbootup` will be executed automatically (without requiring `RUN`). 2- `RUN` will have the additional side-effect of putting each of the commands from the script in your `grunt` history (as if you had executed the commands from the script individually; `EXEC` leaves only the `EXEC` line in history.).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Macros for such things:
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/cont.html#macros

Comment: This is not the correct answer. Macros do enable some code re-usage but they are not the same thing as running an entire Pig script from within another.