# Error while IMPORT Pig Script

Tags: import, apache-pig

A set of macros, jars and properties to be set in every pig latin script file. Have moved all these to common.pig. 
Objective is to include this common pig file in all the pig latin files.

Tried the below approaches as suggested in [Invoke Pig Latin script from other Pig script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20636007/invoke-pig-latin-script-from-other-pig-script)

**Approach 1** : Using RUN, is working as expected.

```
            Usage : RUN  common.pig;
```

**Approach 2** : Using IMPORT is resulting in an error.

```
            Usage : IMPORT 'common.pig';

            Error message :

            ERROR 1200: <file common.pig, line 1, column 0>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'SET'

                org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. <file common_macro.pig, line 1, column 0>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'SET'
                    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1608)
                    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1547)
```

I am trying to understand why the second approach is failing. My understanding of IMPORT is that it writes the imported file directly in to pig script in place of IMPORT statement, if this is the case, ideally it should not have thrown the above error.

Any inputs/ thoughts on this.

Also from code modularity/ maintainability/ execution perspective is it better to go for EXEC or RUN command to call common.pig file in the above  use case.

Files :

**common.pig**

```
SET job.priority HIGH;
-- SET few others ...;

REGISTER snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar;
-- REGISTER piggybank, avro and other required jars
```

**test_import.pig**

```
IMPORT 'common.pig';

A = load 'test/part*' USING  org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage();
DUMP A;
```

Comment: please add the pig files

Comment: @Mzf added common and test_import pig scripts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SET` is not supported in an import file.

Read the [IMPORT Macro](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/cont.html#import-macros) show that [Grunt Shell command](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/cmds.html) are not supported - see below

> Usage Use the IMPORT command to import a macro defined in a separate file into your Pig script.
>
> IMPORT adds the macro definitions to the Pig Latin namespace; these
>   macros can then be invoked as if they were defined in the same file.
>
> Macros can only contain Pig Latin statements; Grunt shell commands are
>   not supported.

Comment: Thank you, I understand that the grunt shell commands are not supported inside IMPORT macro, does this includes the utitlity command - SET ?

Same is the behaviour observed when we have REGISTER command alone in common.pig which we are importing, should this be the case ?

Comment: I think that you can't use the register command in the import file